# Admob Reward Video GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate Undefined symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I recently implemented the admob (ver 7.9.1) reward video based on this tutorial:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/rewarded-video

But I can not compile my app with this feature.
I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "l_OBJC_PROTOCOL_$_GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_CLASS_PROTOCOLS_$_ViewController in libFramework.a(ViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     invocation)
```

I previously implemented the banner and interstitial ads and this worked fine.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing `GoogleMobileAds/GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate.h` and everything is working.

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you that you're not importing the required headers. Did you `import` the `GADRewardBasedVideoAd` header?

```
#import "GADRewardBasedVideoAd.h"
```

Alternatively, you could just import the entire AdMob framework. For example:

```
@import GoogleMobileAds;
```

Google also provides a complete `GADRewardBasedVideoAd` example on GitHub: [RewardedVideoExample/ViewController.m](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/blob/master/Objective-C/admob/RewardedVideoExample/RewardedVideoExample/ViewController.m)

Comment: The header file is imported. Its actually not a compiler error (which means that the header was found and is working) Its a linker error. Sounds like GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate is missing inside the framework

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I also needed to import `GoogleMobileAds/GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate.h`. This is interesting, because banner ad and interstitial ads do not need to import the delegate header.